# copying and renaming multiple files to a hidden folder in a single line command

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

So am trying copy and rename all the .png files to the icons directory as;

```
$ cp /opt/pt/art/{pka.png,pkt.png,pkz.png} ~/.local/icons/{application-x-pka.png,application-x-pkt.png,application-x-pkz.png}
```

but I get the following output error:

```
cp: target '/home/carl/.local/share/icons/application-x-pkz.png/..' is not a directory
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

cp command doesn't accept multiple destinations.

```
$ for a in pka pkt pkz; do
    cp /opt/pt/art/${a}.png ~/.local/icons/application-x-${a}.png
done
```

Comment: There's no need for the `{` and `}` around the `a` here as the next character is not a valid variable name character.

Answer (score -1):

To find all files in the home directory with png, extensions and copy them to `~/backup` (the folders just examples), try:

```
cd
find . -regex '.*\(png\)' \! -path './backup/*' -exec echo cp -t backup {} +
```

And to rename

```
a=1
for i in *.png; do
  new=$(printf "%04d.png" "$a") #04 pad to length of 4
  mv -i -- "$i" "$new"
  let a=a+1
done
```

Comment: This may have been a solution had the question been different. The current question looks for a way to rename the files to specific names under another path.